# How does 'send' call travel through the entire python generator yield hierarchy?

Tags: python, generator, yield

```
def bottom():
    value = yield 42
    print("yield expression in bottom is ", value)
    return value
    
def middle():
    value = yield from bottom()
    print("yield expression in middle is ", value)
    return value
    
def top():
    value = yield from middle()
    print("yield expression in top is ", value)
    return value
    
gen = top()
value = next(gen)
print(value)
try:
    gen.send(value * 2)
except StopIteration as exc:
    value = exc.value
print(value)

# outputs:
# 42
# yield expression in bottom is  84
# yield expression in middle is  84
# yield expression in top is  84
# 84
```

Why did the **send** call travel all the way from top to bottom, shouldn't it have returned from top?

I was expecting the send call to go to the **top** generator and return the value i passed through **send**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one `yield` call in your code, which is in `bottom()`. This is the command that yields 42 and which "receives" the 84 from the `send` command.

You should think of `yield from` statements not as `yield` statements, as they do not themselves yield a value. Rather they create a connection between a "sub-generator" and the function that is calling the generator. This connection is two-ways, i.e. the yield of the "sub-generator" is yielded to the function that is calling and a `send()` from the function that is calling is forwarded to the "sub-generator".

It is actually explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr):

> When yield from  is used, the supplied expression must be an iterable. The values produced by iterating that iterable are passed directly to the caller of the current generator’s methods. **Any values passed in with send() and any exceptions passed in with throw() are passed to the underlying iterator** if it has the appropriate methods. If this is not the case, then send() will raise AttributeError or TypeError, while throw() will just raise the passed in exception immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Sent values are explicitly passed through `yield from ...` expressions to the generator it iterates over. From [6.2.9 Yield expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions):

> When `yield from <expr>` is used, the supplied expression must be an iterable. The values produced by iterating that iterable are passed directly to the caller of the current generator’s methods. **Any values passed in with `send()` and any exceptions passed in with throw() are passed to the underlying iterator if it has the appropriate methods.** If this is not the case, then send() will raise AttributeError or TypeError, while throw() will just raise the passed in exception immediately.

So when you call `gen.send(value*2)`, the value 84 is not yielded directly by `yield from middle()`, but rather sent to `middle` as if you replaced `yield from middle()` with something like

```
# Not tested, may not be entirely correct.
m = middle()
while True:
    x = yield  # Receive value from gen.send(84)
    yield m.send(x)  # Pass that value to m and yield the result
```